# D3.js: scaleTime not working (strange results)

Tags: d3.js

I have found the following chart which uses V3 of d3:
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html

I have tried to port that sample to V5, but I got stuck with scaleTime(). The chart is not displayed correctly.
I have difficulties to debug var x as it is a function ... however if I look at the element svg:clipPath I see this (note the strange values):

```
<clipPath id="clip"><rect x="-8119106.125" y="0" width="0.000008575618267059326" height="361"></rect></clipPath>
```

These are the most relevant parts of my code:

```
var w=1280, h=800;
var svg = d3.select("#zoomable-area-chart").append("svg:svg");
(....)

// Scales
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([h, 0]),

svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", x(0))
    .attr("y", y(1))
    .attr("width", x(1) - x(0))
    .attr("height", y(0) - y(1));

d3.csv("http://localhost/data.csv").then((data) => {

     // Parse dates and numbers.
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parse(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    // Compute the maximum price.
    x.domain([new Date(1999, 0, 1), new Date(2003, 0, 0)]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value;
    })]);

    draw();
});
```

Here you can find a playground for testing: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/qWlLIg2avCe2Kt88r0T5?p=preview

Answer (score -2):

the default domain of `scaleTime` is

> Constructs a new time scale with the domain [2000-01-01, 2000-01-02], the unit range [0, 1]

Why use `x(v)` and `y(v)` to get there ranges when you set them as constants and you can get the range and use `[0]` and `[1]`.

---

Make your zoom-rect fill none, it hides the graph

Comment: @ialarmedalien: I once read in the docs it is just the direction vector and not %, but now at almost the same place they now allow also %

Comment: @rioV8: sorry, I don't get it. I understand that the default value is wrong - but it gets set later, after the http request (async).

Comment: All in all setting the scale seems to work, because I see the y-scale from 0 to 20000. And even if I add the domain properly at the top of the script, the result is the same. Btw - thanks for the hint with the fill:none ...

Comment: @Gerfried you create the clippath **BEFORE** loading data so you use the derfault domain and `0` and `1` have a special meaning in time domain scales